# Android Studio stops working/freezes after updating to Kotlin 1.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Tested Android Studio Versions: 4.0, 4.1, 4.2
Tested Kotlin Versions: 1.4.0, 1.4.10
Tested Gradle Plugin Versions: 4.0.1, 4.1.0
on macOS 10.15.6 Catalina

I have a large project and want to update it from 1.3.72 to the latest Kotlin version 1.4.10.
Kotlin version is set via gradle variable that's used for `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:` and also `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` in the respective modules, so that version is the same throughout the project.

When I set the version to 1.4.10 in the project `build.gradle` and try to build/run the migrations, Android Studio does not stop building and freezes at some point. I have to use "Force quit" to get it running again.

Everything works fine when using the project on kotlin 1.3.72, no problems.
Does anyone know what might be going wrong here?

Comment: From @zachklipp in the kotlin slack: We've had a ton of performance issues with 1.4 in general as well. Afaik everything in Gradle has been fixed as of 6.7, and AGP 4.1.0. There are still a number of kotlin issues that are only fixed in 1.4.20 though, so I'd also try upgrading your Gradle to 6.7 and trying kotlin 1.4.20-M2 (you need to add the repo for pre-release builds: https://kotlinlang.org/eap/configure-build-for-eap.html)